# Moment and date-fns formatting date incorrect

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-fns

I have been trying to format a zulu format date to normal date i.e. MM/dd/yyyy, so far I have tried date-fns and moment. The date I have is `2022-11-03T19:48:24Z` I am expecting it to be formatted as `11/03/2022` but I am getting `11/04/2022`, I do not understand why it is adding a day to the date and how can I fix this ?

```
export function fDate(
  date: Date | string | number,
  template: string = 'MM/dd/yyyy'
) {
  return format(new Date(date), template);
}
```

```
fDate('2022-11-03T19:48:24Z')
```

expected outcome 11/03/2022 but getting 11/04/2022

`format` is coming from date-fns

Comment: You need to post your code for someone to help you.

Comment: Added a code snippet

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `Date` constructor to parse a date_time string when you are using a library like moment.js or date-fns. Instead, use the applicable constructor or methods in the library you want to use.

**moment.js**

The symbols posted in your question do not match the required symbols. The symbols, `d` and `D` have different meanings. The same is the case with `y` and `Y`. Check the documentation page at https://momentjs.com/docs/

The following code produces the correct result as `11/03/2022`.

```
var moment = require('moment');  

console.log(moment("2022-11-03T19:48:24Z").format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

In your code, this will be implemented as

```
return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

**date-fns**

The symbols posted in your question match the required symbols.

The following code produces the correct result as `11/03/2022`.

```
const fns = require('date-fns')

console.log(fns.format(fns.parseISO('2022-11-03T19:48:24Z'), 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
```

In your code, this will be implemented as

```
return fns.format(fns.parseISO(date), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: none of the examples helped

Comment: @YashKaranke - I have added the exact code that you can use. I hope, this helps.

Comment: moment.parseZone(date).format(template) this helped

Comment: @YashKaranke, you do not need to use `moment.parseZone`. The solution provided in this answer meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using moment's `parseZone` helped me

```
export function fDateISOStringToDate(
  date: string,
  template: string = "MM/DD/YYYY"
) {

  return moment.parseZone(date).format(template);
}
```